# Removing noise from data series of road surface data

Tags: filters, python, noise, julia

I have a data series containing underlying noise, the plot of which is :

[image]

The issue is to remove the noise leaving the pattern which is raised above the lower level. The lower level is road surface and the protruding patterns are metalwork, think of them as drain covers or 'manholes'. The noise also appears to some extent in the patterns (see the middle one). I cannot expect the road surface noise to go completely, asphalt is not flat it has texture (or it would be like ice) however the patterns are geometric in nature and are defined.

The x-axis is distance (meters), around one reading per mm, the y-axis is mm. Velocity can be considered constant.

Attempts to resolve this have been.

Savitzky–Golay filter. This reduces the resolution of the signal, rounding off the corners in the pattern. The pattern is reduced to a series of curves.

signal.medfilt (median filter) This does not reduce the pattern resolution but increasing the kernel size also rounds the corners while removing the noise to some extent.

Butterworth low pass or high pass, This flattens the data (plot) and I will need to measure the metalwork/pattern in the final filtered data.

Attempting to use a fourier transform approach has me completely puzzled as examples are of a form where, "we create noisy data, then take out the noise we created". I have the noisy data it just needs to disappear. Most of the frequencies are close together and are a bit random.

Is there a method to remove the noise (it's a combination of road surface and the laser scanning it) leaving the image of the metalwork.

The final requirement after this will be to measure the height (or amplitude) of the pattern and the distance between the peaks.

Suggestions as to where to explore next would be appreciated (correcting my thoughts are not a problem). More than one sequential step to do this is acceptable in python or julia.

P.S I've been sent over here from Stack Overflow in the hope that you folks may know more.

Comment: Have you tried the Lower-upper median filter?

https://reproducibility.org/RSF/book/jsg/strfilter/paper_html/node6.html#:~:text=The%20lower%2Dupper%2Dmiddle%20(,and%20the%20other%20for%20sharpening.

Comment: There isn't enough information for a right answer here.  No, you cannot perfectly filter the noise from the signal -- sorry.  You can only come closer to whatever you need.  To know what sort of filtering may work, we need to know more about the model -- importantly, things like whether the metal is always raised, whether it's always level with the road, whether it's always the same extent, etc., etc.  We also need to know what sort of accuracy you're looking for, possible what you're trying to do with the output, and what features you need in that output.